# Hyperledger Fabric orderers throwing faulty node error status: NOT_FOUND

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-orderer

I have 5 ordering nodes (version 2.4) running on my cluster. I tried to rotate their tls certs and made some mistake. The network is a dev network and now all the ordering nodes are throwing below mentioned error:

```
2022-03-25 10:18:13.947 UTC 014c WARN [orderer.common.cluster.puller] fetchLastBlockSeq -> Received status:NOT_FOUND  from orderer1.org1.com:7050: faulty node, received: status:NOT_FOUND  channel=assetschannel
2022-03-25 10:18:13.947 UTC 014d WARN [orderer.common.cluster.puller] func1 -> Received error of type 'faulty node, received: status:NOT_FOUND ' from orderer1.org1.com:7050 channel=assetschannel
2022-03-25 10:18:13.948 UTC 014e WARN [orderer.common.cluster.puller] fetchLastBlockSeq -> Received status:NOT_FOUND  from orderer4.org1.com:7050: faulty node, received: status:NOT_FOUND  channel=assetschannel
2022-03-25 10:18:13.948 UTC 014f WARN [orderer.common.cluster.puller] func1 -> Received error of type 'faulty node, received: status:NOT_FOUND ' from orderer4.org1.com:7050 channel=assetschannel
2022-03-25 10:18:13.948 UTC 0150 WARN [orderer.common.cluster.puller] fetchLastBlockSeq -> Received status:NOT_FOUND  from orderer2.org1.com:7050: faulty node, received: status:NOT_FOUND  channel=assetschannel
2022-03-25 10:18:13.949 UTC 0151 WARN [orderer.common.cluster.puller] func1 -> Received error of type 'faulty node, received: status:NOT_FOUND ' from orderer2.org1.com:7050 channel=assetschannel
2022-03-25 10:18:13.949 UTC 0152 WARN [orderer.common.cluster.puller] fetchLastBlockSeq -> Received status:NOT_FOUND  from orderer0.org1.com:7050: faulty node, received: status:NOT_FOUND  channel=assetschannel
2022-03-25 10:18:13.949 UTC 0153 WARN [orderer.common.cluster.puller] func1 -> Received error of type 'faulty node, received: status:NOT_FOUND ' from orderer0.org1.com:7050 channel=assetschannel
2022-03-25 10:18:13.953 UTC 0154 WARN [orderer.common.cluster.puller] fetchLastBlockSeq -> Received status:NOT_FOUND  from orderer3.org1.com:7050: faulty node, received: status:NOT_FOUND  channel=assetschannel
2022-03-25 10:18:13.953 UTC 0155 WARN [orderer.common.cluster.puller] func1 -> Received error of type 'faulty node, received: status:NOT_FOUND ' from orderer3.org1.com:7050 channel=assetschannel
```

Since it is a dev network, I can reset the entire network but I want to consider this scenario as if it occurred on a production network and because we can not reset a production network, I would like to get some suggestions on how we can recover the ordering nodes from this error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, If we have backup of the ledger and WAL, we can restore them & bring up the network. Otherwise, we need to reset the network.